# Unable to activate watir-screenshot-stitch-0.7.4, because rubyzip-2.3.0 conflicts with rubyzip (~> 1.2) (Gem::ConflictError)

Tags: ruby, watir

ERROR : Unable to activate watir-screenshot-stitch-0.7.4, because rubyzip-2.3.0 conflicts with rubyzip (~> 1.2) (Gem::ConflictError)

The above error is displayed when trying to run job from jenkins

It has started coming up after i upgraded ruby

Any ideas around what can be the root cause of this error and what can be done to resolve the same.

Comment: I met up with the same problem and created a bug report here https://github.com/samnissen/watir-screenshot-stitch/issues/60

Comment: ......And if you follow the bug report, they have offered the solution as to how to group the gems. I still haven't tried.

Comment: There is a gem file in our framework buti cudnt understand how to do the logical grouping of gems within the same...?

Comment: What I did was I just downgraded rubyzip to 1.2 and it works. Try the same

Answer (score 1):

I removed rubyzip-2.3.0 gem from the path as 'Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems..
This resolved the issue.

NOTE: rubyzip--1.3.0 remains in the above mentioned path as is.

Comment: I did the same. So it works. But remember there are some other gem which dependent on rubyzip 2.3.0 wouldn't work. So this is the work around.